# Bind an inputText to a function by pressing enter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to bind the value in my inputtext so that i can the value inside this inputtext in a function and that should only happend if pressed enter on my inputtext.
Any ideas ?

I used this combination but the textvalue in the inputtext did not set as in the field:

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="setInListElement"
                 actionListener="#{bean.addToInList(bean.inText)}"/>
    
<h:inputText value="#{bean.inText}"
             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13){ setInListElement; return false; }"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml ?

Comment: Thank you very much. that was exactly what i am looking for. you are the best